# Highcharts - Pass a dictionary as data for a timeline series

Tags: python, django, highcharts

So, I've been using Highcharts for quite a while, and I was trying to make a Timeline Chart. I've seen some example code on the internet and noted that the data attribute is basically a dictionary. So I made a dictionary from some data, using python/pandas etc, and it looks like this:

```
[{'name': '2017-12-07 - Chat',
  'label': 'some text',
  'description': 'some text'},
 {'name': '2017-12-15 - Whatsapp',
  'label': 'some text',
  'description': 'some text'}]
```

I pass this in a context in django and then call it in the html template, together with the js code for the chart:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var _dict = {{dict|safe}};
  </script>
  <script src="/static/vendors/highcharts/cs_timeline.js"></script>
```

And then in the javascript file, I use the dict as the data attribute, using some code I've got from the official Highcharts example:

```
Highcharts.chart('hist', {
    chart: {
        type: 'timeline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Timeline of Space Exploration'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Info source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_space_exploration">www.wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            connectorColor: 'silver',
            connectorWidth: 2
        },
        data: _dict
    }]
});
```

This works fine for every chart I've done, but isn't working for this one. 
I'm having trouble identifying where the problem is; the format, the dictionary, some text I've messed up, if it's even possible to do this, or something. Help would be appreciated!
~first post, sorry for anything~

Comment: I've reproduced it in the jsfiddle and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k8apmLsr/. Which version of highcharts do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don’t have any real date data. The closest I see is a string that starts with a date. Highcharts definitely needs dates in order to present a time series.

Comment: Hello! I thought of this, but in the Highcharts example (https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/timeline/) it doesn't seem to be any date/datetime series or similar, so I think it isn't needed for this kind of chart.

Comment: That fiddle was illustrative. I replaced his data with the data you gave, and it works in the fiddle. (Color me surprised.) Have you tried the same?

Comment: Yeah, this bugs me to; The data works fine in the fiddle. The hist is just the name of the div/container, so it shouldn't matter much, I think.